# How does scalability compare between MVVM Javascript & tranditional ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, mvvm, knockout.js

How does scalability match up in these two architectures? (For a web app)

I.E I can see that for MVVM javascript, we have;

### Advantages:

-A share of the logical processing required, is executed on the client's browser. So for **n** requests,
the client browser's take this load from the server **n** times. (E.G iterating through collections to output HTML)

### Disadvantages:

-More requests per user. I.E For the initial dynamic HTML, in Traditional, we have 1 request per user, but in MVVM we may have up to 5 for initial HTML. I.E,

1. Request 1, use get's initial HTML
2. Request 2-5, Knockout clients, requests's JSON data, so it can setup lists, and dynamic HTML etc.

No doubt these JSON requests, can be Asyncronous actions, but even so, how badly will this effect load?

Comment: They are not mutually exclusive. You can use mvc and mvvm pattern in your UI. This might be useful when you have intial data loading and then other data loading later after a user interaction.

Comment: don't see you comparing server load difference between a simple json data API vs loading a backend framework to produce a page, or considering content change speed difference in client side app ( user experience)

Comment: yes I'm aware they aren't mutually exclusive. Also, yes I'm not interested into user experience here, as I know as long as there aren't too many round trip requests & the infrastructure meets the requirement the user experience will satisfy me

Comment: @Baconbeastnz seems like you're the only user of your software then if you can certainly say that the user experience will satisfy you :)

Answer (score 2):

When you build a SPA-style app, the advantage is that once the initial page is loaded, the next requests will be smaller requests than usual. After all, you will only be requesting data as opposed to HTML + data.

In terms of the effects on server load, it'll depend on your app. If the bottleneck is in data processing (fetching from db, domain logic, ...) either approach will have more or less the same load, since you have to process the data anyway.
If on the other hand the bottleneck is in the rendering, the client-side approach will be more beneficial since the rendering will be done on the client.